# An object of Eloquent Model call the constructor again when calling get method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I know that a constructor of an object only call for the first time when it's created.

But in my case, after using xDebug to investigate, I found that despite being called successfully with the `$blockId` parameter when it was created, when I call the `get()` method to get data, the constructor get called again, and this time, the `$blockId` parameter is just an empty array so that it caused errors.

I try another case with `count()` method, it works like a charm.

Here is the code I mentioned above:

```php
$userData = new UserData($blockId);
$results= $userData ->whereIn('Type', request('user_types'))->get(); //causes error
$results1= $userData ->whereIn('Type', request('user_types'))->count(); //works like a charm
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserData extends Model
{
    const TABLE_NAME  = 'user_';

    protected $table = self::TABLE_NAME;
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function __construct($blockId)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->table .= $blockId;
    }
}
```

I hope you could help me to know what the cause is. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That won't work.
When querying existing model, under the hood [there is a `(new static)->newQuery()` call](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L945), so your data is lost. You should rethink your flow.

Answer (score 0):

The get() method returns an array of models.
This means the constructors get called for each returned database row.
Set the $blockId as a optional parameter, or use a data attribute with existence check.